# Check if user is on page?

Tags: php

I have a question about php.

I've made a *login/register* page, where the user can choose right for login and left for register. I've done the left and right with including the `login.php` and `register.php` from the root of my map.

The problem is when users type `login.php` or `register.php` behind the web address, they get to the actual page with no style etc.

How can I check that the users are on the `both.php` page and if they try to access the `login.php` or `register.php` by typing it manually, automatically redirect them to `both.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is possible, you can check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at the top of `login.php`, like so:

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/login.php') !== false){
    header('Location: /both.php');
    exit;
}
```

You would do the same for `register.php`, ***however***, redirecting your users from those pages is not the best solution; instead you should move `login.php` and `register.php` outside of your webroot. Any file that you don't want the user to have access to should be outside the webroot.

Let's say that your webroot is called 'public_html'. Then create a directory structure like so:

```
public_html:
 - both.php
includes:
 - login.php
 - register.php
```

Then in `both.php`, to include the other two files, do:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../includes/login.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../includes/register.php';
```

Since those files are outside the webroot they cannot be viewed by typing a path into the address bar, but `both.php` can still include them.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I still used the redirect, that suits best for my website atm!

Comment: @Kets You're welcome! Keep in mind that it is better for security reasons to move your scripts outside your webroot and sometimes better for SEO (both.php won't make much sense as a login form to Google), if you move everything outside you webroot and use a front controller you can easily control which url loads which resources.